# Who is Saint Assam?

Tags: catholicism

Who is Saint Assam? 
How is he related to Assam of India?

If anyone may please help me with the answers of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

[**St. Assam**](http://catholicsaints.info/saint-asicus-of-elphin/) is a local saint of Ireland. Nothing about him is related to the people from [Assam in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_of_Assam), other than the spelling of his name.

> St. Assam, the patron saint of Raheny, appears in lists of saints over the centuries, with a feast day of April 27th, but detail is lacking. Spelt Sanc. Aazanus, St. Ossan or St. Assan in the past, this shadowy figure may be the same as St. Ascicus, first Bishop of Elphin (an ancient Diocese in the Roscommon area), may have been an early disciple of St. Patrick and may have been a worker in brass. - [Raheny History](http://www.raheny.com/history.htm)

The confusion with his name is quit understandable as it has several different translations.

> The earliest reference to Raheny is one linking it to a saint in 570 A.D. and tradition has it as an early Christian site. Later it came under the power of the major monastery of Inis Neasan.
>
> St. Assam is the local saint; he was also known as St. Assan (and other forms besides, Aazanius in Latin, for example, and perhaps St. Ascicus) and was possibly a disciple of St. Patrick. A Holy Well of St. Assam was active (in what are now the grounds of the Catholic church) until sometime in the last century and is now concealed. More popular until later was the Holy Well of St. Anne, now within the bounds of St. Anne's Park and sadly dry.
>
> In the centre of the village, on an island of land between roads, stands the ruin of the Church of St. Assam. The old church was built in 1712, probably replacing a building of 1609, itself a successor on a church site which the tradition has going back nearly 1500 years (it lies within the bounds of the rath or fort for which Raheny is named). This was in ruins by the early 20th century and was eventually transferred from the Church of Ireland to Dublin Corporation, in whose care it now rests. - [Religion in Raheny](http://www.raheny.com/religion.htm)

Wikipedia has this to say about [St. Assam's Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Assam%27s_Church):

> St. Assam's is the name of two historic churches in the village of Raheny, Dublin, one a picturesque ruin in the middle of the village, one the structurally sound but no longer primary church built for the local Roman Catholic community of the area after the revival of religious rights. Both buildings lie within the area of the ráth (ring fort) which gave the village and district its name, and which was perhaps 110 m across.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. I was born in Assam, India and thinking of doing a business in Dublin. The client office is in St. Assam. Got very confused. We know Srimanta Sankardeva, a Hindu priest as Saint of Assam. He propagated north Indian Hindu culture in north-east India, in pre-Muslim era.

Comment: @RichardParker You are most welcome. I hope the information proves useful.